# PHP: constant as variable in function

Tags: php, constants, type-hinting

I'm trying to use constant as a function paramter, is it possible to check type of this constant.

Example of what I want:

```
class ApiError {
  const INVALID_REQUEST = 200;
}

class Response {
  public function status(ApiError $status) {
    //function code here
  }
}
```

USE:

```
$response = new Response();
$response->status(ApiError::INVALID_REQUEST);
```

This shoud check that given $status is constant of class ApiError. Is something like this possible?

Comment: status(ApiError $status) expects instance of ApiError class not the constant value

Comment: I know, that's why i'm asking "How to do it"

Answer (score 11):

As the others mentioned, there is no generic solution. But if you'd like to do it in a very clean way, model every "object" that you're dealing with (= every possible status), e.g.:

```
interface ApiError {   // make it an abstract class if you need to add logic
    public function getCode();
}

class InvalidRequestApiError implements ApiError {
    public function getCode() {
        return 200;
    }
}

// Usage:
$response = new Response();
$response->status( new InvalidRequestApiError() );

class Response {
    public function status(ApiError $status) {
        echo "API status: " . $status->getCode();
    }
    // ...
}
```

This leaves you with a lot of classes, because you encapsulate simple numbers, but also with the ability to type-hint.

Comment: I hate the in_array() proposal because it's array-oriented programming as opposed to object-oriented.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `in_array()` to test against whitelisted values, which is a recommended strategy whenever you need to validate input to a specific value set:

```
// Test if it is in an array of valid status constants...
$valid_statuses = array(
   ApiError::INVALID_REQUEST, 
   ApiError::INVALID_SOMETHINGELSE, 
   ApiError::STATUS_OK
);
if (in_array($status, $valid_statuses)) {
   // it's an acceptable value
}
```

To whitelist all constants of a class, you could use reflection and retrieve the constants from `ApiError` [via `ReflectionClass::getconstants()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php)

```
$refl = new ReflectionClass('ApiError');
$valid_statuses = $refl->constants();
```

Answer (score 2):

An other approach would be to change the call.
If we want to check if the const is existing, this line would be too late.
`$response->status(ApiError::INVALID_REQUEST);`

The php interpreter will also check the const for existence and will die with a Fatal Error.
That is not catchable using try().

So I would suggest to use string as a parameter to check the existence using **defined()** and **constant()**

```
class ApiError {
  const INVALID_REQUEST = 200;
}

class Response {
  public function status($status) {
    if (!defined('ApiError::'.$status)) {
      return false; // Or throw Exception / other error handling
    }

    $errorCode = constant('ApiError::'.$status);

    //function code here
    return true;
  }
}
```

The use would then look like this:

```
$response = new Response();
$response->status('INVALID_REQUEST');
```

Bad thing is that there is no type hints for this solution.

Comment: IMO this is the best answer if you need to keep constants.

Answer (score 1):

I like this approach best:

```
class NoticeType {
    const INFO = 'neutral';
    const WARN = 'alert';
    const FAIL = 'critical';
    const PASS = 'success';
    const LITE = 'brand';

    private $_type;

    function __construct($NOTICE_constant)
    {
        if (!preg_match('/neutral|alert|critical|success|brand/', $NOTICE_constant))
            throw new \Exception('Invalid parameter for '.__CLASS__.' constructor');
        $this->_type = $NOTICE_constant;
    }
    function getType() {
        return $this->_type;
    }
    function __toString() {
        return $this->_type;
    }
    static function INFO () {
        return new NoticeType(self::INFO);
    }
    static function WARN () {
        return new NoticeType(self::WARN);
    }
    static function FAIL () {
        return new NoticeType(self::FAIL);
    }
    static function PASS () {
        return new NoticeType(self::PASS);
    }
    static function LITE () {
        return new NoticeType(self::LITE);
    }
}
```

Usage is very straight-forward and you would have to go out of your way to mess up:

```
function test (NoticeType $n) {
    echo ($n == NoticeType::INFO)."\n";
}

test (NoticeType::INFO());
```

Answer (score 0):

[SplEnum](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splenum.php) could help. 
Example from PHP docs:

```
class Month extends SplEnum {
    const __default = self::January;

    const January = 1;
    const February = 2;
    const March = 3;
    const April = 4;
    const May = 5;
    const June = 6;
    const July = 7;
    const August = 8;
    const September = 9;
    const October = 10;
    const November = 11;
    const December = 12;
}

echo new Month(Month::June) . PHP_EOL;

try {
    new Month(13);
} catch (UnexpectedValueException $uve) {
    echo $uve->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
6
Value not a const in enum Month
```